# Как моментально отследить кнопку Power на android?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, как можно моментально отследить кнопку Power? В этом примере кода она срабатывает только после того, как пройдет некоторое время и откроется экран выключения.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

        Intent intes = new Intent("com.example.off.Black");
        startActivity(intes);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандартной ситуации перехват кнопки питания запрещен, это сделано сознательно, чтобы очумелые ручки не смогли ввести девайс в неприемлемый режим.

Имеется не очень документированный пермишен: `android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY` (надо декларировать в манифесте), который позволяет получить контроль за кнопкой питания, а именно ловить нажатие кнопки питания без долгого ожидания:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Power button short press!");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Поскольку пермишен недокументированный не гарантируется работа на всех девайсах.